# How to read a memory dump in binary from GDB?

Tags: linux, c++11, gdb

At the time of a crash I have a post crash handler where I try to dump whats in certain memory regions

```
auto memdump = std::fstream("FileMemDump.bin", std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
auto memRegion = getMemoryRegion();
std::cout << "Memory region start: " << memRegion.start << " size: " << memRegion.size;
memdump.write((char*)memRegion.start, memRegion.size);
memdump.close();
```

and after the file has created a core file 
So after I load the core in the following manner :

```
#gdb ./exec ./core.file
```

I give the restore command; the start address is what is printed from the above log... and it fails with the following message

```
(gdb) restore ./FileMemDump.bin binary 0 0xFFAA0000
You can't do that without a process to debug.
```

a. Are the options given to the `std::fstream` OK or

b. Is it possible call the `gdb-dump` command from with in the code (since dump from gdb can be restored)

or what I am trying to do is not feasible

---

EDIT:

1. The big picture : In my process I want to use memory mapped IO  --   at the time of init I allocate huge pages and `mmap()` it to a `/dev` device and similarly I `mmap()` the nonvolatile dimm area as well (we do not use conventional malloc)

With this ; when the process asserts/cores I am not able to access the hugepages  or the non volatile dimm areas

2. I was trying to have a post fatal hook where I dump these memory areas into a binary file(s). In this question I was asking to restore those memory areas into the GDB core to inspect those memory areas

---

Arguments to mmap()

```
fp = open("/dev/mem", O_RDWR);
mmap(NULL,
     region.size,
     PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
     MAP_SHARED | MAP_NORESERVE,
     fp,
     phybaseaddr);
```

Comment: Do you have an http://xyproblem.info/ ? "what I am trying to do is not feasible" -- you didn't tell us what you are trying to achieve, and "restoring" data into a core dump (without a live process and its associated memory) makes no sense.